# Cubic polynomials over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, finite-fields, programming

I was watching an introduction video on "Tangent conics and tangent quadrics" by Prof. Norbert Wildberger , where the following Taylor polynomial was introduced:

$$p_r(x) = (a+br+cr^2 + dr^3) +(b+cr + 3 *dr^2)(x-r) + (c + 3 *dr)(x-r)^2$$

He chose specific values, $a=5, b = -3, c =-4, d = 1$ and then computed simply the complete table for all $r$ and $x$ over the field $F_{11}$, field modulo 11

He then obtained a very nice result I added at the bottom of this post: There are multiple interesting things to notice, but I found immediately nice that in the first column all values from 0 to 10 appeared and then wondered: How many of these polynomials have this property over this field and other?

Therefore I wrote a Python code snippet and brute forced the count for the fields $F_2$ to $F_{19}$ and got these numbers:

$$16, 70, 198, 698, 1130, 1130, 1130, 1130, 1130, 5130, 18440, 18440, 18440, 18440, 45440, 45440, 124048, 124048, 124048$$

After $N=5$ for $F_N$ a pattern seems to emerge. The question now is: Is there actually a pattern or is it just some coincidence? Can one compute them in a smarter/faster way?

Thank you in advance!

Below the code used to generate the numbers, the table mentioned above and an image of it in case it cannot render.

```
import numpy as np

tangentConic = lambda a, b, c, d, x, r: (a + b * r + c * r ** 2 + d * r ** 3) + \
                                        (b + 2 * c * r + 3 * d * r ** 2) * (x - r) + \
                                        (c + 3 * d * r) * (x - r) ** 2

Ns = np.arange(2, 20)
count = 0
for N in Ns:
    for a in range(N):
        for b in range(N):
            for c in range(N):
                for d in range(N):
                    computes = np.zeros((N, N))
                    for j in range(0, N):  # a-xis shift
                        for i in range(0, N):  # x axis
                            res = tangentConic(a, b, c, d, i, j)
                            red = res % N
                            computes[N - 1 - red, i] = j
                    complete = True
                    firstCol = computes[:, 0]
                    for num in range(N):
                        if num in firstCol:
                            continue
                        else:
                            complete = False
                    if complete:
                        count = count + 1
    print("N: ", N, "count: ", count)
```

\begin{array} {|r|r|} \hline 3 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 10 & 5 \\ \hline 5 & 0 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 9 & 7 \\ \hline 9 & 5 & 10 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 2 \\ \hline 7 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 4 \\ \hline 1 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 8 \\ \hline 0 & 9 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline 10 & 4 & 9 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 0 \\ \hline 4 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 10 & 1 & 10 \\ \hline 1 & 10 & 2 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 5 & 3 & 9 \\ \hline 6 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 3 \\ \hline 8 & 2 & 6 & 10 & 10 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}

[image]